# How to resolve DI on Program.cs before app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I follow this [link from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to use root level cascading values. (dotnet 8 RC2)

```
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddCascadingValue(s =>
        {

//  get a service here to retrieve data for currentSeason...
            var currentSeason =
                new CurrentSeasonModel { SelectedStageId = 65 };
        
            return new CascadingValueSource<CurrentSeasonModel>(
                    "abc",
                    currentSeason,
                    isFixed: true);
        });
```

However, how can I get a dynamic value from database for currentSeason by resolving DI at this point before the app

```
    var app = builder.Build();
//    app.Services.GetService<IService>
```

Comment: To get an instance of `CascadingValueSource` or `CurrentSeasonModel`? Can't you just call the lambda function?

Comment: instead of a hard coding currentSeason (selectedstageid=65), I need to retrieve data from database, like  ISeasonService.GetCurrentSeason() => to bind to currentSeason.

Comment: `AddCascadingValue(s =>`in here `s` is `IServiceProvider` which you can resolve services with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know 2 solutions.
Solution1: use Sqlconnection to read database. Then you needn't DI Context.
Solution2:
Student

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=192.168.2.68;Initial Catalog=Test05;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxx;TrustServerCertificate=True"));

var dbContext=builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<MyContext>();
var value = dbContext.Student.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Test
[image]